Bootstrap Modal header css variable not defined - var(--bs-modal-header-padding) not defined
I am not using modal-header inside modal
I want to use modal-header css property, inside normal div
But css property has values when its inside modal but it shows variable not defined when used in normal div
Please help me know what I am missing
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-b2QcS5SsA8tZodcDtGRELiGv5SaKSk1vDHDaQRda0htPYWZ6046lr3kJ5bAAQdpV2mmA/4v0wQF9MyU6/pDIAg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha512-X/YkDZyjTf4wyc2Vy16YGCPHwAY8rZJY+POgokZjQB2mhIRFJCckEGc6YyX9eNsPfn0PzThEuNs+uaomE5CO6A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <div class="modal-header">Modal header to test with padding and border-bottom</div>
    <div class="modal-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam sequi, rem iusto maxime est nostrum voluptatem tempore soluta aspernatur qui repellendus incidunt. Maiores similique aut ratione a facilis voluptatum error totam quibusdam quo, amet eum? Dicta incidunt sit dolorum atque id, eum eius, ea officia est voluptatem quod suscipit perferendis, tempore laborum consequatur ipsum. Ipsam, nemo!</div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary">Secondary</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>```


The --bs-modal-header-padding variable is defined in the .modal rule.
Because your .modal-header is not inside a .modal, it doesn't recognize the variable.

But If I use .modal for parent div, the html document completely disapperas

A bootstrap modal is not displayed by default (.modal contains display:none). It's supposed to open on some events you define. (Doc Bootstrap Modal 5.3, note that modals shown there contains d-block because without it, it wouldn't be displayed by default)
